# When/ why did Barnabas kill the hippies?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark-shadows

Near the end of the movie Dark Shadows, Angelique plays a confession she secretly recorded of Barnabas killing "Dr. Hoffman, and those workmen, and some very nice unshaven people."

I remember Barnabas sitting and talking with a group of hippies, but I must have missed him killing them (assuming they were the unshaven people he mentioned)- did he kill those hippies and if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_M592zuu7BY), he says he is going to kill them and seconds after you can hear the screams. The reason the act itself isn't shown is because it's still a comedy that includes some younger audiences.

Why he did it can be two different reasons or a combination of it. He might have done it to sate his appetite for blood, he is a vampire after all. And the hippies are the best target he could get, seeing they were roamers without any ties to the community. If he had killed a local police would investigate causing him troubles...but a band of roaming hippies, who would even know that they were gone?

The second reason might be that he did confide some of his past/curse in to them, something he is supposed to keep a secret for his plans to restore the family pride to work.